# JavaScript - Filtering an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of arrays of data returning to me back from a csv file. I am attempting to filter out each index of an array depending on which title is in the array. For example:

If an index of the array has the name "Retail" return that entire index which includes some values.

Here is my array :

```
[     
    ​​[
     "Retail",
    ​​
     "22,477",
    ​​
     "24,549",
    ​​
     "19,580",
    ​​
     "15,358",
    ​​],       ​    ​
     [ 
      "Online", 

      "8,653", 

      "7,586",

      "2,432",

      "4,321"
    ],

     [ 
         "In Store", 

          "2,532", 

          "2,836", 

          "5,632",

          "7,325" 
     ]
]
```

I've attempted these two separate ways and both are returning an array of 0:

```
filtArr = dataList.filter(name => name.includes('Retail')) //expecting the array length 5 with "Retail" and it's values
```

attempt 2

```
 filtArr = dataList.filter(function (name) {
    return (name === "Retail")
})
```

Expected return is: `console.log(filtArr) // [ 0. "Retail", 1. "22,477", 2. "24,549", 3. "19,580", 4. "15,358"`

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataList, null, 2))` and share an example of that response by [edit]ing your question. The output of `console.log(dataList)` introduces a lot of extra cruft that simply doesn't exist in the data.

Comment: your `dataList` seems incomplete, your first attempt seem more accurate with what you want to do, as in the second attempt you try to compare the datarow (array) with a string.

Comment: Your latest edit can't be the output of `JSON.stringify(dataList, null, 2))`. It's missing the surrounding `[]`, and it's missing some `,`.

Comment: @Barmar my apologies, that was from typos on my own end

Comment: How can there be typos? Doesn't your computer have copy and paste?

Comment: I was editing the text to fix with formatting it on the page. The results were pretty clear on what they were returning before I fixed the typos.

Comment: FYI, when I pasted it into my answer, there were a bunch of invisible Unicode characters mixed in with the whitespace in the first sub-array. I'm not sure what they are.

Comment: I can't reproduce your original problem with this array. `name => name.inclues('Retail')` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to check if an array contains some item is to test it with the indexOf method.
It will return -1 if the item is not found or else its index.

You could do this to store all arrays containing 'Retail' in them:

```
let retailArrays = [];
arrayOfArrays.forEach( 
    array => {
        if( array.indexOf('Retail') !== -1) {
        retailArrays.push(array);
        };
    }
)
```

Comment: Why is this better than `.includes()`?

Comment: you can't put `if` after `=>`. You need to put it inside `{}` body.

Comment: You're basically just reimplementing `filter()` and `includes()` with your own code. Why do you think it will work better than the original?

Comment: both work for me when I run them so I'm confused but I don't really appreciate your vibe Barmar, if my answer helps him good but I don't feel like talking to you

Comment: A good answer should identify something that was wrong in the original code, and show how to fix it. What do you think he was doing wrong, and why do you think your code will solve the problem? If they're equivalent, then they'll both run into the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have trailing spaces after some of the names, so maybe `"Retail"` is actually `"Retail "`.

It also looks like the name is always the first element of the nested array, so there's no need to search the whole array.

So use `trim()` on the first element to remove the surrounding spaces.

```
filtArr = dataList.filter(arr => arr[0].trim() == 'Retail');
```

```js
var dataList = [
  [
    "Retail",
    "22,477",
    "24,549",
    "19,580",
    "15,358",
  ],
  [
    "Online",
    "8,653",
    "7,586",
    "2,432",
    "4,321"
  ],
  [
    "In Store",
    "2,532",
    "2,836",
    "5,632",
    "7,325"
  ]
];
filtArr = dataList.filter(arr => arr[0].trim() == 'Retail');
console.log(filtArr);
```

Comment: This answer was written before the edit that removed the trailing spaces. But I'm not sure I believe that edit.