# Removing first index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that i'd like to remove the first index of an array before. I've looked up some examples and saw that `.shift()` is the quickest and easiest method to use in what I am trying to accomplish.

so I declare a variable `stateData` to equal the original `array.shift` my console.log log is still returning the first index of my array. Alternatively I tried `array.slice(1)` but when console logging `stateData` I am getting back an empty array.

It does not seem that my syntax is off with either of these methods so I am not sure why this is not working.

I am expecting to have the first index of the array removed.

Here is my array:

```
arr:
Array(10) [ "States", "207,390", "205,020", "160,502", "110,073", "62,681", "35,069", "43,716", "45,471", "58,549"]
```

My expected outcome is have the return array display without having "States" in index zero. Only return the string of numbers.

Here is my code:

First attempt:

```js
var arr = ["States", "207,390", "205,020", "160,502", "110,073", "62,681", "35,069", "43,716", "45,471", "58,549"];

function drawGraph(arr) {
  let stateData = arr.shift()
  console.log(stateData, "stateData") // Array(10) [ "States", "207,390", "205,020", "160,502", "110,073", "62,681", "35,069", "43,716", "45,471", "58,549"]
}
drawGraph(arr);
```

Second Attempt:

```js
var arr = ["States", "207,390", "205,020", "160,502", "110,073", "62,681", "35,069", "43,716", "45,471", "58,549"];

function drawGraph(arr) {
  let stateData = arr.slice(1)
  console.log(stateData, "stateData") // console.log returns Array(0) []
}
drawGraph(arr);
```

Comment: Could you please include where your `console.log()` statements are in your code and what they're logging? Even better would be a runnable StackSnippet

Comment: From [MDN's documentation of `shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift): "The **`shift()`** method removes the **first** element from an array and returns that removed element."

Comment: `arr.shift()` removes and remove the first element. So when you do `let stateData = arr.shift();` the variable `arr` is modified and now `stateData` store the removed element.

Comment: @Phil I've edited my code to replicate what I have locally, im not too sure on how to include a runnable stacksnippet.

Comment: I don't think your array contains what you think it does. Looks more like it's an array of arrays

Comment: [Here's how to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes?

Comment: Taking a wild swing here but I think you want `arr[0].slice(1)`

Comment: @DaveNewton Same reason all often-asked dupes do; because someone else wondered the same thing and didn't feel like searching either ;).

Comment: The second version should work.

Comment: Are you working on the same project as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945834/javascript-filtering-an-array-of-strings/61945975#61945975)? There, `filtArr` is the result of calling `filter()`, so it's a 2-dimensional array, not a single array as you show.

Answer (score -1):

The return value of the Array's shift method is the removed item.
just use arr.shift() which will change original array.